# Converting 32bit to 64bit Assembly (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, assembly, 64-bit

As a learning project I wanted to convert the 32bit Execve script from [here](http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/04/demystifying-execve-shellcode-stack.html) so it works on 64bit. However I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to execute it. I stepped through it with GDB and found the problem instruction. My current code is as follows:

```
.section __DATA,__data
.section __TEXT,__text
.globl _main
_main:
xor %rax, %rax
push %rax

push $0x68732f6e
push $0x69622f2f

mov %rbx, %rsp

===>push %rax ;this is where the error occurs
mov %rdx, %rsp

push %rbx
mov %rcx, %rsp

mov %al, 11
int $0x80
```

Comment: [The original script](http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/04/demystifying-execve-shellcode-stack.html) uses Intel syntax, whereas you use AT&T syntax, but you forgot to switch the order of parameters. In **Intel** syntax the parameter order is **dest, src**, whereas in **AT&T** syntax the parameter order is **src, dest**.

Comment: FYI, that's not going to be enough. 64 bit syscall convention is different, and also the two pushes won't create a contiguous string because they are 64 bit too.